# Qual a diferença entre .data() e JQuery.data()?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tava lendo a documentação do jquery e não entendi muito bem qual a principal diferença entre dois ja que ambos servem pra armazenar dados a partir de uma tag html.

Comment: Boa pergunta, +1..mas acredito que o mais usado é o .data()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A unica diferença entre **.data()** e **JQuery.data()** é que **JQuery.data** é um método de **baixo nivel**, comparado com **.data()**.

Comparando o **codigo** entre os dois, **.data()** é muito mais **usual**.

Veja a diferença:

```
$("div").data("test");
```

---

```
var div = $("div")[0];    
jQuery.data(div,"test");
```